# Why do the most structurally well-characterized bacterial RNA polymerases belong to thermophiles?

Tags: polymerase, xray-crystallography, thermophilia

From Lewin's Genes (11th edition, page 515):

> The only bacterial RNA polymerases for which high-resolution crystal structures have been solved, however, are from two thermophilic bacterial species, *Thermus aquaticus* and *Thermus thermophilus*.

Is this just a matter of economy? I mean, as X-ray crystallography is exceedingly expensive and complex, did scientists consider enough to resolve the RNA polymerase structure of one species and deduce those belonging to the rest by homology-based folding prediction?

Or is it because thermophilic proteins are inherently more stable and thus easier to crystalize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both of your suggestions have some merit: (1) [it appears that *Thermus* RNAPs are more stable and easier to crystallize](https://www.nature.com/articles/261725a0) (2) RNAP is highly conserved and so it is not critical to crystallize it from every bacterial species.

Comment: It might be worth adding that knowledge about thermostable enzymes is generally economically interesting since it is often easier to use them in various experimental settings, especially after optimising/engineering them - which becomes much eaiser with structural information.

Comment: The Nature article provided by @canadianer states that they were succesful isolating the core complex (that is, alpha dimer, beta, beta-prime and omega), but not the holoenzyme (the previous ones with sigma). I suggest that is because sigma leaves the RNA pol complex once elongation (the longest phase) begins; so researchers have a shorter window of time to isolate the holoenzyme.